# jQuery Want to get rid of multiple click statements

Tags: jquery, html, simplification

Here is my website that I've been working on: http://jaakkouusitalo.fi/new As you can see there is those four colored squares, all of the have different classes.

I would like to simplify it, making if and and else statements. I lack skills of knowing what to do so I decided to ask directly here.

Here is my html file:

```
    <section>
        <h2>Color combination should be following:</h2>
        <ul class="colors">
            <li class="color-img1">
                <img src="img/1.png" />
                <div class="caption1">
                    #FFD800
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="color-img2">
                    <img src="img/2.png" />
                    <div class="caption2">

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="color-img3">
                    <img src="img/3.png" />
                    <div class="caption3">
                        #587498
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="color-img4">
                    <img src="img/4.png" />
                    <div class="caption4">
                    #E86850
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Currently I'm handling my jQuery like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

            $('.caption1, .caption2, .caption3, .caption4').hide();

            $(".color-img1").hover(function() {
                $('.caption1').show();
            });

            $(".color-img2").hover(function() {
                $('.caption2').show();
            });

            $(".color-img3").hover(function() {
                $('.caption3').show();
            });

            $(".color-img4").hover(function() {
                $('.caption4').show();
            });
        });
```

I think there is better way to make this. I just don't know how.

Comment: Hello, I am going to use what kieran suggested below. Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be with CSS, and I have listed the CSS solution below. However first will answer with the javascript solution.

Please see a JS Fiddle of the results:

- JavaScript version: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh8xM/1/
- CSS version:http://jsfiddle.net/53X25/

**Javascript Solution**

Simplify your HTML to just use .caption instead of .caption1,2,3,4 and .color-img instead of 1,2,3,4:

```
<section>
    <h2>Color combination should be following:</h2>
    <ul class="colors">
        <li class="color-img">
            <img src="img/1.png" />
            <div class="caption">
                #FFD800
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img">
                <img src="img/2.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                #FFD800
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img">
                <img src="img/3.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                    #587498
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img">
                <img src="img/4.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                #E86850
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

And change your javascript like so - comments inline explaining what it does:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.caption').hide();
        //use .on (and mouseover) syntax over .hover
        $(".color-img").on("mouseover", function () {
        //find child element .caption, and show
        $(this).find('.caption').show();
    });

});
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh8xM/1/

**CSS Solution**

Use the simplified HTML as per the javascript version, but in CSS all you would need to do is have:

```
.caption { 
  display:none;
 }
.colors li:hover .caption {
 display:block;
 }
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/53X25/

Comment: I am going to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  $(".color-img1,.color-img2,.color-img3,.color-img4").hover(function() {
        idnum=$(this).attr('class').replace( /^\D+/g, '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")                
        class="caption"+idnum;
        $('.'+class).show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step one**

use CSS to make .captionX hidden using `display:none;` then you won't need the original hide statement.

**Step Two**

use a single bind `$(".colors img").hover(function() {}` then show the caption relevant to the object that is "hovered" using `$(this).parent("li").children(".caption").show()` or something similair.

Comment: With display:none keep in mind that if Javascript is off, you will never see the caption, while something like `$('.caption').hide();` will show the caption if javascript is disabled (this may be good or bad depending on what you really want). You should set your page to how you want it with JS disabled, then modify it with JS if available.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$("ul.colors").children('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('div[class^="caption"]').show();
});
```

This hover function is activated when you hover on any `li` child of `ul.colors`; then calls `show()` on any `div` child element the `li` may have whose class begins with "caption".

Alternatively you can make use of jQuery's `on()` method:

```
$("ul.colors").on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
    $(this).children('div[class^="caption"]').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the same class on all buttons to simplify, see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FaUSG/

As you can see you can use two or more class names separated by space as in the example: `class="color-img color-img1"`

`color-img` takes care of common behaviour (what applies to all the buttons), 
`color-img1` takes care of single button behaviour (like button color for instance)

```
<section>
    <h2>Color combination should be following:</h2>
    <ul class="colors">
        <li class="color-img color-img1">
            <img src="img/1.png" />
            <div class="caption">
                #FFD800
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img color-img2">
                <img src="img/2.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                    HERE?
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img color-img3">
                <img src="img/3.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                    #587498
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="color-img color-img4">
                <img src="img/4.png" />
                <div class="caption">
                #E86850
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

This way the code reduces to:

```
$(function() {
        $('.caption').hide();

        $(".color-img").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find('.caption').show();
            },
            function() {
                // uncomment this if you also want to hide it at rollout
                // $(this).find('.caption').hide();
            }
        );
});
```